# Search SQL table, hide personal information

Tags: sql, oracle, hide

I am refining a search in Oracle. I need to search people by SSN but cannot display SSN on the SQL table. 
How do I visually hide SQL data on the table but still be able to use the hidden data in a search?

Comment: what `oracle` version are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle 12C

Answer (score 1):

As with Oracle 12c,
there is a provision of **Invisible columns** that you can set so that columns are not visible (for e.g) during `DESCRIBE`.

You can create a table where `coluna3` is defined as invisible using the INVISIBLE keyword.

> SQL> CREATE TABLE tabela_col_inv (
>   coluna1 NUMBER,
>   coluna2 NUMBER,
>   coluna3 NUMBER INVISIBLE,
>   coluna4 NUMBER  );
>
> Table created.

To display the `INVISIBLE` columns in that SQL session, you will have switch `COLINVISIBLE` to `ON`

```
SQL> SET COLINVISIBLE ON
```

During *invisibility*,

> the column can still be accessed via DML and DDL statements

Your search (`SELECT`) should work in this case as well.

More details are on this [Invisible Columns in Oracle Database 12c](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/database/invisible-columns-odb12c-2331522.html) page.